# NumLock ON in logon screen (Lubuntu 14.04)

Tags: lubuntu, 14.04, numlock

I just installed a danish version of the Lubuntu 14.04 and I have fought with this problem = NumLock is OFF when the logon dialog comes up AND my users have numbers in their passwords !

I have tried, I would say, ALL of the methods I found in this forum and none of them worked.

I shall say that some methods describes dialogs that I don't have or that looks different and DON*T have the fields mentioned in that method.

Other methods describes adding a line to files that are NON-EXISTENT or have no content at all - and if I that add the line described as the only line in that file, the machine wont start.

I'm very frustrated to be the only one in the world where NumLock can't be set ON in the logon dialog.

I'm NOT that skilled in this LINUX world, so bare with me.

Do you have a bullet proof method that can bee used to set the NumLock ON when the logon dialog is shown on the screen after re-boot ?

Comment: Ha, ha, I just wnt through this text 5 min before writing my question - and none of it works - or are SO different, or non-existing files or empty files - that's why I asked.

Answer (score 1):

Install `numlockx`. It works for me.

```
sudo apt-get install numlockx
```

Comment: Not enough I think/know -when the logon dialog is on the screen I want the NumLock to be ON - and your answer just installs the numlockx - I have tried all methods I could find in here in the forum - included what you say - so I think a little more sophisticated method is needed. I think if that works for you, then you must have some more "defaulf-stuff-content" in some files somewhere in you system.